# GNU make: variables in pattern rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How variables are expanded in pattern rules and static pattern rules? Patterns are matched using global variable values, but recipes can use target specific and pattern specific variable values. Did I get it right?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have it right, but your question is a little unclear. Maybe you could come up with an example of what you mean... and then you could *try it*, then ask us about the parts you're still puzzled about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) is quite clear on this; at least for target-specific variables, but the way I understand it, it works the same for pattern-specific variables. It states (on target-specific variable values):

> these values are only available within the context of a target's recipe

So they are not used in the patterns, but only in the recipes.